# Main construct of logic programming paradigm

Tags: logic, paradigms

We say that:

1. in procedural paradigm the main construct is the 'procedure';
2. in OOP paradigm the main construct is the 'object';
3. in functional paradigm the main construct is the 'function';

but what's in logic paradigm? axiom? predicate?

I'm confused.

Comment: I'd say logic clauses such as facts (A is true) or rules (A is true if B is true).

Comment: Is this a terminology question? Clearly, it's a statement of the form "...(...) :- ...".

Answer (score 1):

[Horn Clauses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause)

From Wikipeida

> Horn clauses are also the basis of logic programming, where it is
>   common to write definite clauses in the form of an implication:
>
> In fact, the resolution of a goal clause with a definite clause to
>   produce a new goal clause is the basis of the SLD resolution inference
>   rule, used to implement logic programming and the programming language
>   Prolog.

EDIT

Since OP is trying to relate predicates (first-order predicate logic) to horn clauses

See: Translation of first-order predicate logic to horn clause logic: in [Logic Programming](http://www.emu.edu.tr/aelci/Courses/D-318/D-318-Files/plbook/logic.htm) by Anthony A. Aaby

I tried to reproduce the instructions here to avoid link rot, but I could not figure out how to put a list in a quoted section.

Comment: Is it different from the predicate?